# jquery load html and hide and show

Tags: jquery

I am calling the following code to load a html into the div.

```
        $('#strap').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#collection_content').load('collection_sub.html');

    });
```

And I call this to make it disappear

```
$('#collection_content').hide();
```

but when I try to load the same html file again, it doesn't show anything.. is it because it is hidden?  How should I make it appear it again?  for now, 'collection_sub.html' is static, but it is going to be replaced with a php dynamic page, so i want to re-load it.. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make it appear again, just call `.show()`:

```
$('#collection_content').show().load('collection_sub.html');
```

If the element is already visible, `.show()` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

`.load` .`hide` and `.show`

In here u are going to click the id = strap then it will loading a collection_sub.html page into the div are collection_content.so if you want to hide after it loaded u need to ue it like this.And if u want to show it when click the #strap again u want to use it like bellow

```
       $('#strap').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#collection_content').load('collection_sub.html',function(){
    $('#collection_content').hide();

     $('#strap').click(function(e) {

    $('#collection_content').show();

      });

  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, it is, when the `#strap` element is clicked several handlers are called.